# Tangent values in Hermite Curves

Tags: c++, bgi

I am trying to draw curves using Hermite method in C++. I know that two points are starting and ending points while other two give tangents at the two ends. End points can be guessed directly, but how to decide the value of tangents. When I give simple values, I either end up on a straight line or a loop in the curve.

My code is as:

```
//Using tangents

#include<iostream>
#include "graphics.h"
//#include"DDALine.h"
using namespace std;

void calcP(float P0x, float P0y, float R0x, float R0y, float P1x, float P1y, float R1x, float R1y, float Px, float Py, float t){
    Px = (2 * t * t* t -3*t*t +1)*P0x + ( t*t*t - 2 *t*t +t)*R0x + (-2 * t*t*t + 3*t*t )*P1x +(t*t*t -t*t )*R1x;
    Py = (2 * t * t* t -3*t*t +1)*P0y + ( t*t*t - 2 *t*t +t)*R0y + (-2 * t*t*t + 3*t*t )*P1y +(t*t*t -t*t )*R1y;
            putpixel(Px, Py, WHITE);
}

int main(){
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

    float t = 0;
    float P0x = 71, P0y = 165, R0x = -12, R0y = 2, P1x = 210, P1y = 153, R1x = 108, R1y = 0, Px= 0, Py = 0, Pz = 0;
    while(t<1){
        calcP(P0x, P0y, R0x, R0y, P1x, P1y, R1x, R1y, Px, Py, t);
        t+=0.001;
    }

    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help! In dire need. :)

Comment: If you don't have tangents as input, then Hermite curves are the wrong model to use. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The simplest choice is with the Cardinal Splines.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two points it is hard to define the tangents in any meaningful way. The natural choice is to set them to 0. This will only draw a line between the points which of course is not very exiting.

The simple way to define the tangents, if you have more points, is so called cardinal spline. For a point k the tangent is given

R<sub>k</sub> = (1-c)(P<sub>k+1</sub>  - P<sub>k-1</sub>)

c is a parameter between 0 and 1. c=1 gives you the straight lines and c=0 more curved answers.

If you want to test it easily with your current code. You can imagine points -1 and 2, e.g., with P<sub>-1</sub>=(10,10) and P<sub>2</sub>=(150,120). This gives tangents with (c = 0)

R<sub>0</sub> = (200, 143) and R<sub>1</sub> = (79, -45)

which should give some curvature to the line.

If you want more complicated tangents you can try [Kochanek-Bartels spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kochanek%E2%80%93Bartels_spline) (Wikipedia), which has three parameters (tension, bias, and continuity) to control the interpolation.